# laravel echo : "Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined"

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, pusher, laravel-echo

im trying to work laravel echo with pusher , im working on windows localhost (wamp / laravel 5.8)

so i've installed required libs

my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.8.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "pusher-js": "^6.0.3",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    }
}
```

resources/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.xxx = 'xxx';
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});
```

i ran

```
npm run dev
```

here is the result

[image]

in my view i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
        console.log(Echo);
    </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

i keep getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined
```

i even added

```
window.xxx = 'xxx';
```

in bootstrap.js to see if i can eccess xxx variable in my view but thats undefined as well (btw im not sure if thats how it works !!  just trying some stuff )

any idea ?

my folders structure is like

```
/pusher (root folder)
  +app
  +vendor
  +node_modules
  +resources/js
  -public
    index.php
    css/app.css
    js/app.js
```

Comment: maybe try `window.Echo = require('laravel-echo');`?

Comment: @admcfajn thanx , same error

Comment: Try removing `defer` from `<script ..`

Comment: @marco-a damn thing was in the laravel default layout and i didn't even notice it ! pleas post is as answer so i ca reward the bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `defer` from the `<script ..` portion.